# Evaluate $ \int\limits_{0}^{\mu}x^{-3/2}e^{-\sigma/x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How does one go about analytically evaluating the improper integral
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\mu}x^{-3/2}e^{-\sigma/x}dx,
$$
where $\mu,\sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$? There may be some standard analytical formulae out there for this type of integral, I'm not sure.

Some context: The integral arises in dabbling with the (reflected) Levy distribution, which is an example of an extremely heavy-tailed distribution, with the tail index of 0.5. It has some other very weird properties.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the definition of the [complementary error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html) $$\text{erfc}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{z}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt.$$

So let $u=\frac{\sqrt{\sigma}}{\sqrt{x}}$ then ${dx}=-\frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sigma}}du$ and we have

$$\int_{0}^{\mu} x^{-\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{\sigma}{x}}dx=-\int_{\infty}^{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{\mu}}}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}e^{-u^2}\frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sigma}}du$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\sigma}}\int_{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{\mu}}}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-u^2}du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\sigma}}\text{erfc}(\sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{\mu}}).$$

Comment: Why do we need the integration constant $C$ for a definite integral? Is $erfc(z)$ strictly positive? What does $\cal{R}$ stand for? If it's the real part, I did say in the question that both $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are positive and real.

Comment: I made a typo, we don't need $+C$ of course, I've fixed it. Thank you. $R$ stands for real part, and I've seen that both $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are real and positive, but it also works for complex numbers too! (whose real part is $>0$). $\text{erfc}(z)$ is a decreasing function as you can see from the link.

Comment: In your change of variable $u:=\frac{\sqrt{\sigma}}{\sqrt{x}}$, when $x=0$, $u$ is undefined. Are you saying that $u:=\frac{\sqrt{\sigma}}{\sqrt{0}}=+\infty$? Why?

Comment: Since $\sigma>0$, then we've taken $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{\sigma}}{\sqrt{x}}=+\infty$.

Comment: Alternatively you can consider the power series expansion of $e^{-\frac{\sigma}{x}}$ and go from there.

Comment: But, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{\sqrt{\sigma}}{\sqrt{x}}$ is undefined. (I'm talking about the left handed limit at $0$).

Comment: In this case $x$ is between $0$ and $\mu>0$, so we approach from $0^{+}.$

Comment: Can you apply your approach to $\int\limits_{0}^{\mu}x^{-1/2}e^{-\sigma/x}dx$ instead? What do you get?

Comment: You can use the power series expansion $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and then apply [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). However the problem with this method is that the integrand must be positive and finite (which is not the case). Regardless it can be expressed as special functions such as the complementary error function (or Incomplete Gamma function) as seen above.

Comment: Expressing it in terms of the incomplete gamma function doesn't work in this case. The first argument of $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a negative real number, which is inadmissible.The only only other option is to try the complementary error function - which leads to an integral of the form $$\int\limits_{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{2\mu}}}^{+\infty}u^{-2}e^{-u^2}du.$$ How do you even go around something like this?

Comment: You would integrate by parts and then use the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html).

Comment: I don't see how integration by parts would be successful here, especially with the $u^{-2}$ term. Let $U=?$ and $dV=?$.

Comment: Let $U=e^{-u^2}$ and $dV=u^{-2}.$

Comment: No what I've written is correct. To use the complementary error function we needed the $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ coefficient, so that's why I multiplied by $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. So we have $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\sigma}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\pi}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\sigma}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

Comment: My calculation gives $$\int\limits_{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{2\mu}}}^{+\infty}u^{-2}e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt{\frac{2\mu}{\sigma}}e^{-\sigma/2\mu}-\sqrt{\pi}\;\text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{2\mu}} \right).$$

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

WLOG $\sigma=1$ by rescaling the variable.

$$\int x^{-3/2}e^{1/x}dx=-\int u^{-1/2}e^{-u}du=-2\int e^{-t^2}dt$$ which is a well-known Gaussian integral.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\mu}x^{-3/2}
\expo{-\sigma/x}\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu, \sigma\ \in\ \mathbb{R}^{\large +}}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\sigma/x\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over \root{\sigma}}\int_{\sigma/\mu}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}
\expo{-x}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\Gamma\pars{1/2,\sigma/\mu} \over \root{\sigma}}
\\ &\
\end{align}

$\ds{\Gamma\pars{\ldots,\ldots}}$ is the
[Incomplete Gamma Function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E2).

Comment: Is the first argument of the upper incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ allowed to be negative? I'm curious what would happen to your formulation if you were looking at $\int\limits_{0}^{\mu}x^{-1/2}e^{-\sigma/x}dx$ instead.

Comment: @user775349 No problem, in that case, because $\displaystyle\sigma/\mu > 0$.

Comment: I get $\Gamma(-1/2, \sigma/\mu)$  multiplied by some constant. Does this make sense? I read somewhere that the first argument of $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ must be positive (or have a positive real part.).